# Github Pages SCSS File not Being Read

Tags: html, github, sass, github-pages

I'm not sure why but my Github Pages website will not read my scss file even though it's in the repo. I don't think I need to include my code here but if you take a look at my repo you can see it there within the css folder https://github.com/jamesemcc/jamesemcc.github.io and properly linked in the index.html head. Yet if you go to my site https://jamesemcc.github.io/ it's not reading anything from my styles.scss. Thanks for any help!

Comment: Browsers don't load and interpret Sass. Your `index.html` should be linking to a `css` file and not a `scss` file.

Comment: @BlackEnigma thanks, I've been working within rails the past few months and forgot there's nothing here to compile the scss. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I think you just need to start your Sass file with two lines of triple dashes (see docs https://jekyllrb.com/docs/assets/) and link to the `.css` file in your markup, not `.scss`, which browsers don’t support.

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/scss" href="css/style.css">`

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I'm actually not using Jekyll. I've been working in rails and forgot that the scss file won't compile on it's own.

Comment: Ah, ok, figured you were using Jekyll :) sassc-rails would be my recommendation for that https://rubygems.org/gems/sassc-rails/versions/0.0.1